# Magento 1.9: Copy all products of a category to another category

Tags: magento-1.9, category, category-products, copydata

I want to copy all products from one category to another category in Magento 1.9.2.2?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below script to copy products from one category to other.

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');

error_reporting(1);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');

//  COPY Products From => To
//  5 => 10
$from = 5;
$to = 10;

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($from);

$productCollection = $category->setStoreId(1)->getProductCollection();

foreach($productCollection as $_product) {
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());

  $newCategories = $origCats = $product->getCategoryIds();
  if(!in_array($to, $origCats)) {
    $newCategories = array_merge($origCats, array($to));
    $product->setCategoryIds($newCategories)->save();
    echo 'Assigned -- ' . $product->getId() . '<br />';
  }
}
echo 'Completed Execution!!!';
?>
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Upload below script in magento 1 root and then run below URL

> http://www.example.com/copycat.php?id=[CATEGORY ID TO COPY]

```
<?php
if(!is_numeric($_GET['id']))die('Please specify a category ID');

$catId = $_GET['id'];

$xml = simplexml_load_file('app/etc/local.xml');
$host = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->host;
$username = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->username;
$password = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->password;
$dbname = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->dbname;
$res = mysql_pconnect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($dbname);

$catsDone = 0;
duplicate_entity($catId);

// Fix the children count for all (sub)categories
$sql = "CREATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_tmp LIKE catalog_category_entity";
mysql_query($sql);
$sql = "INSERT INTO catalog_category_entity_tmp SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity";
mysql_query($sql);
$sql = "UPDATE catalog_category_entity cce
SET children_count =
(
SELECT count(cce2.entity_id) – 1 as children_county
FROM catalog_category_entity_tmp cce2
WHERE PATH LIKE CONCAT(cce.path,'%')
)";
mysql_query($sql);
$sql = "DROP TABLE catalog_category_entity_tmp";
mysql_query($sql);

echo $catsDone . ' Categories duplicated.';

function duplicate_entity($id, $parent_id = null){
global $catsDone;

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
// Grab category to copy
$sql = "SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity WHERE entity_id = " . $id;
$query_entity = mysql_query($sql);

$entity = mysql_fetch_object($query_entity);

if(!$parent_id)$parent_id = $entity->parent_id;

mysql_query("INSERT INTO catalog_category_entity (entity_type_id, attribute_set_id, parent_id, created_at, updated_at, path, position, level, children_count)
VALUES ({$entity->entity_type_id}, {$entity->attribute_set_id}, {$parent_id}, NOW(), NOW(), '', {$entity->position}, {$entity->level}, {$entity->children_count})");
$newEntityId = mysql_insert_id();

$query = mysql_query("SELECT path FROM catalog_category_entity WHERE entity_id = " . $parent_id);
$parent = mysql_fetch_object($query);
$path = $parent->path . '/' . $newEntityId;

mysql_query("UPDATE catalog_category_entity SET path='". $path."' WHERE entity_id=". $newEntityId);

foreach(array('datetime', 'decimal', 'int', 'text', 'varchar') as $dataType){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_".$dataType."
WHERE entity_id=" . $entity->entity_id;
//die($sql);
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($value = mysql_fetch_object($query)) if (is_null($value->value)) {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO catalog_category_entity_".$dataType." (entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)
VALUES ({$value->entity_type_id}, {$value->attribute_id}, {$value->store_id}, {$newEntityId}, NULL)");
} else {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO catalog_category_entity_".$dataType." (entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)
VALUES ({$value->entity_type_id}, {$value->attribute_id}, {$value->store_id}, {$newEntityId}, '{$value->value}')");
}
}

//for Products
$sql = "SELECT * FROM catalog_category_product WHERE category_id = " . $id;
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($value = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
$sql="INSERT INTO catalog_category_product (category_id, product_id, position)
VALUES ({$newEntityId},{$value->product_id},{$value->position})";
echo $sql;
if(!mysql_query($sql))
echo("Error");
}

$sql = "SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_category_entity WHERE parent_id = " . $id;
$query = mysql_query($sql);

while ($entity = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
duplicate_entity($entity->entity_id, $newEntityId);
}
$catsDone++;

}

?>
```